# Sampling distribution of the mean confusion

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, definition, normal-distribution, sampling

Say we have some population and decide to randomly take a sample of size $n$ from this population.  What does it then mean to talk about the *distribution of the sample mean*?

In other words, what do we mean by the *distribution of the sample mean* here?

---

I’m quite confused about this as from what I understood from my textbook, it doesn’t make sense to talk about a distribution of a sample mean in this scenario (since we are looking at one sample).  Obviously, I’m wrong, but I’m not seeing why.

Comment: So if we randomly take a sample of size $n$ from the population, each possible selected sample outcome will have a mean, and those means will then have a distribution.

Comment: But then we are not looking at **one** sample of size $n$, but rather at **all** possible samples of size $n$?

Comment: You could think this way. But even if you only select one, since you select this one randomly, it means you have lots of possibilities for this one selection, and it obeys certain distribution that's tied back to your population.

Comment: I see, yes. It's starting to make sense now.

Comment: The key word is thus the "randomly" part.

Comment: Sort of. If you say I select "1,2,3,4" out, then the mean is definitely 2.5

Comment: Hum, so then the context is also crucial?  That is, since we are talking about *distribution* of the sample mean in this case, and clearly we can't have a distribution of one mean (of say 2.5), we are forced to interpret this as you explain in your first comment?

Comment: No, I did not mean that. I just give you a sense: if you say "we randomly select one sample out" or you say "we select one sample out" - you are talking about the distribution. But if you say "we select 1, 2, 3, 4" out, then even if you select 10 times, there is still no distribution.

Comment: Okay, I see.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take $n$ i.i.d. samples from a population with a particular distribution, you can then take the mean of the sample.  This sample mean will also be a random variable, and will have its own distribution, called the *distribution of the sample mean*.

In particular, the mean of the distribution of the sample mean will be the mean of the original distribution for the population, while the variance of the distribution of the sample mean will be the variance of the original distribution for the population divided by $n$ (assuming these exist).

So the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean, while the likely error will reduce as the sample size $n$ increases.

As an example, suppose the population is exponentially distributed with rate $1$ (so its mean is $1$ and its variance is $1$), and you take a sample of size $n=4$.  You might get data like one of the following rows

```
          X1          X2          X3         X4    sample mean
 [1,] 0.3929842 0.59443344 0.03191802 0.1188843 0.2845550
 [2,] 0.3873812 0.20919761 1.53515619 1.6538193 0.9463886
 [3,] 0.1229839 0.75581917 0.06593355 0.7986400 0.4358442
 [4,] 2.0959258 0.97214578 0.40010242 0.4257327 0.9734767
 [5,] 0.3621020 0.14805365 0.22586113 3.3202165 1.0140583
 [6,] 2.4047787 0.10890730 1.14527881 0.6846319 1.0858992
 [7,] 0.3713004 0.09458689 2.71174074 1.7904559 1.2420210
 [8,] 0.1483070 0.92459828 0.63327521 3.1271168 1.2083243
 [9,] 0.1239702 0.43675343 2.55238171 0.8339072 0.9867531
[10,] 0.6990532 0.23775550 0.90174834 0.5666429 0.6013000
```

and you may be able to see that many different values are possible, but the sample mean often tends to be closer to $1$ than the individual sample.  In this example, the individual samples have an exponential distribution by construction as shown by the blue density in the chart below, while the mean has a stretched gamma distribution (which would get closer in shape to a normal distribution if the sample size were increased) as shown by the red density below, more concentrated around $1$.  It is this red density line which shows the *distribution of the sample mean*

[image: distribution of the sample mean]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Stephen, it seems you have a good intuitive understanding
of the idea of 'standard error.' Here is an elementary statement of some
basic facts so that you will know the precise terminology involved.

**Estimation of $\mu$ when $\sigma$ is known.** If you are starting with a normal population with unknown mean $\mu$ and known SD $\sigma,$ then the sample mean $\bar X$ is the estimator of $\mu.$ In this
context $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is called the *standard error of the mean*.
Perhaps the most common application is that a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is of the form $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

**Estimation of $\mu$ when $\sigma$ is unknown.** If you are starting with a normal population with *unknown* mean $\mu$ *and* variance $\sigma^2,$ then $\bar X$ is estimator of $\mu$ and the sample variance
$S^2$ is the estimator of $\sigma^2;$ with $E(\bar X) = \mu,\,$ $E(S^2) = \sigma^2,\,$ $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n,\,$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

Then the standard deviation of the mean $SD(\bar X) = \sigma \sqrt{n}$ is again
called the *standard error of the mean.* However, because $\sigma$ is unknown, the
the ***estimated** standard error of the mean* is $S/\sqrt{n}.$ By abbreviation or sloppiness, the word "estimated" is sometimes dropped and one refers to $S/\sqrt{n}$ as the "standard error of the mean."

In this case, a 95% CI for $\mu$ is of the form $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$
where $t^*$ (cutting probability 2.5% from the upper tail of Student's t
distribution with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom) can be found from printed
tables or using software.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n=1$ and $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent and identically distributed and $$X_1 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } 1/2, \\ 2 & \text{with probability } 1/2. \end{cases}$$
The sample mean is $(X_1+X_2 + X_3)/3.$

You have
$$
(X_1,X_2,X_3) = \begin{cases} (1,1,1) \\ (1,1,2) \\ (1,2,1) \\ (1,2,2) \\ (2,1,1) \\ (2,1,2) \\ (2,2,1) \\ (2,2,2) \end{cases}
$$
each with probability $1/8.$ Therefore
$$
\frac{X_1+X_2 + X_3} 3 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } 1/8, \\ 4/3 & \text{with probability } 3/8, \\ 5/3 & \text{with probability } 3/8, \\ 2 & \text{with probability } 1/8. \end{cases}
$$
That is the probability distribution of the sample mean.

Answer (score 0):

As a relative newcomer to statistics, this confused me also. Similar wording is often used when comparing a single sample to the sampling distribution. When wording like this is used, they do not mean the sampling distribution was generated from that one sample, they are referring to the sampling distribution generated from all possible samples of the same size as the single sample.